# Check nested object contains any propeties with null value

Tags: c#, json, json.net, .net-6.0, json-deserialization

I have a result response object which I need to deserialize and convert to a JSON object which looks like this:

```cs
var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var deviceSeqNrResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
```

and `deviceSeqNrResponse` looks like

```
{
    "dataMod": 1,
    "deviceId": "myDeviceID",
    "seqNum": [
      {
          "ApplicationType": null,
          "exampleId": 8
      }
    ]
}
```

and I am trying to test this logic to see if there are any properties in `"seqNum": []` which is nested in the result object. I tried `.Contains` and other approaches with no success.

I am using .NET 6.

What I am trying to achieve is that:

> Assert there is no property with null values in `"seqNum": []` equals to true.

Comment: Please show us the "approaches" that you have tried, in a [minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405791/what-should-a-minimal-reproducible-example-include-for-problems-with-automati), so that we have a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1: Wih *Newtonsoft.Json***

1. Select the element "sequenceNumbers" via `.SelectToken()`.
2. Get all the values from *1* (return nested arrays). Flatten the nested array via `.SelectMany()`.
3. With `.Any()` to find any element from the result *2* with `Type == JTokenType.Null`.
4. Negate the result from *3* to indicate there is no element with the value: `null`.

```cs
JToken token = JToken.Parse(responseBody);

bool hasNoNullValueInSeqNumber = !token.SelectToken("sequenceNumbers")                                                    
                                .SelectMany(x => x.Values())
                                .Any(x => x.Type == JTokenType.Null);
```

**Approach 2: With *System.Reflection***

1. Get all the public properties from the `SequenceNumber` class.
2. With `.All()` to evaluate all the objects in `SequenceNumbers` list doesn't contain any properties with value: `null`.

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

bool hasNoNullValueInSeqNumber = typeof(SequenceNumber).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .All(x => !deviceSeqNrResponse.SequenceNumbers.Any(y => x.GetValue(y) == null));
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/73Ajuw)